Multiple flutter module method channel issue
I have two flutter module lets say module A and B. I have included module B into module A.
In module B's flutter screen added a button and calling a method startSDK which is handled in module B native android code in FlutterActivity. By using method channel I am able to communicate within the same module from flutter to native method call.
Now module B is imported into module A and when the module B flutter screen button clicked it throws method not found because it goes to module A FlutterActivity instead module B FlutterActivity.
Please share your thought if anyone faced similar kind of issue.
